# PhysicalModelLayer DETACHED When Rendering Card Flutter

Tags: flutter, rendering, card

I am having an issue when scrolling to the end in a list of Card widgets in a Flutter Web app. Minimal code to recreate the issue is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TournamentHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const TournamentHome({Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          children: List<SizedBox>.generate(
            tournaments.length,
            (int index) => SizedBox(
              width: 400,
              height: 200,
              child: InkWell(
                child: Card(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The only thing I can say is, this doesn't happen in every such page. What I have noticed is that this occurs when the number of cards generated is 45. It doesn't occur when it's 35. Also this occurred when I resized the browser. So guess the issue might be down to the number of card rows that is being rendered.

Complete error is below:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
Assertion failed:
org-dartlang-sdk:///flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/html/path/path_ref.dart:905:12
isValid
is not true

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Card Card:file:///C:/Users/chari/Flutter/wt20_info_admin/lib/widgets/schedule_home.dart:40:24

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49  throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3    assertFailed
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/html/path/path_ref.dart 905:12             debugValidate
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/html/path/path_ref.dart 421:5              shiftedFrom
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/html/path/path.dart 64:27                  shiftedFrom
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/html/path/path.dart 1285:19                shift
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 2026:31                                                                      paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 79:14                                                                      paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 140:14                                                                       paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 140:14                                                                       paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 140:14                                                                       paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 140:14                                                                       paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 140:14                                                                       paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 140:14                                                                       paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2844:14                                                                            defaultPaint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/wrap.dart 774:7                                                                             paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 79:14                                                                      paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 187:12                                                                          paintChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart 551:16                                                          paintContents
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 387:12                                                                          pushLayer
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 443:7                                                                           pushClipRect
packages/flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart 555:39                                                          paint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2477:7                                                                          [_paintWithContext]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 141:10                                                                          _repaintCompositedChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 100:5                                                                           repaintCompositedChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 995:29                                                                          flushPaint
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 506:19                                                                         drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 892:13                                                                           drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 370:5                                                                          [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1146:15                                                                        [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1083:9                                                                         handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 997:5                                                                          [_handleDrawFrame]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1090:13           invoke
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 160:5             invokeOnDrawFrame
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/initialization.dart 194:45                 <fn>

The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPhysicalShape#047ed:
  needs compositing
  creator: PhysicalShape ← _MaterialInterior ← Material ← Padding ← Container ← Semantics ← Card ←
    Listener ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← Semantics ← MouseRegion ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(4.0, 4.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.0, h=192.0)
  layer: PhysicalModelLayer#672d7 DETACHED
  size: Size(392.0, 192.0)
  elevation: 1.0
  color: Color(0xffffffff)
  shadowColor: Color(0xffffffff)
  clipper: ShapeBorderClipper
This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
    child: RenderCustomPaint#b78c9
      child: _RenderInkFeatures#00ec0
        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#0f5cf
          child: RenderFlex#0a077
            child 1: RenderPadding#533c8 relayoutBoundary=up1
            child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#eb681 relayoutBoundary=up1
            child 3: RenderConstrainedBox#abfb8 relayoutBoundary=up1
            child 4: RenderConstrainedBox#792a6 relayoutBoundary=up1
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Flutter Doctor is below:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.67.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: couldn't generate the exception from your minimal code! it works just fine ,did you try to run it as windows app for example, instead of web? could you upload a video of the error ?

Comment: first: in flutter-web better way is running app and track errors on devTools .
second: please add result of (flutter doctor -v) in your post.

Comment: Once I upgraded to the latest flutter/dart version the issue had resolved. I am not sure how that is. Thanks for the feedback but for now the issue is not getting recreated!

Answer (score 0):

According to official documents;
"Simply doing so, however, usually results in a conflict between the Column, which typically tries to grow as big as it can, and the SingleChildScrollView, which provides its children with an infinite amount of space."

You can try the code block below.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Center(
       child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
             minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          ),
          child: Wrap(
             children: List<SizedBox>.generate(
                45,
                (int index) => SizedBox(
                   width: 400,
                   height: 200,
                   child: InkWell(
                      child: Card(
                         child: Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: Text("$index")
                         )
                      ),
                   ),
                ),
             ),
          ),
       )
    ),
)
```

If you are considering a long list, it will be more efficient if you use "ListView.builder". I tested the list of 1000 items below on dartpad.

```
Center(
   child: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: 400,
      child: ListView.builder(
         addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
         addRepaintBoundaries: false,
         itemCount: 1000,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
             return SizedBox(
               width: 400,
               height: 200,
               child: InkWell(
                  child: Card(
                     child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Text("$index")
                     )
                  ),
               ),
            );
         },
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: Once I upgraded to the latest flutter/dart version the issue had resolved. I am not sure how that is. Thanks for the feedback but for now the issue is not getting recreated!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the SingleChildScrollView with a `Container` of

```
height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, 
width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

Right now it doesn't have a bound and it may break the UI if you have content that goes outside the screen

Comment: Once I upgraded to the latest flutter/dart version the issue had resolved. I am not sure how that is. Thanks for the feedback but for now the issue is not getting recreated!

Comment: don't recommend expensive widgets like Container when you can use SizedBox for a fixed height and width!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a performance bug in the flutter SDK.

Also, for more efficiency, consider using a `ListView` and more specifically a `ListView.builder` when you have a scrollable list of identical widgets.

The [Flutter official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) recommend using this method as it only builds the widgets that are visible in the screen.

> **The ListView.builder** constructor takes an IndexedWidgetBuilder, which
> builds the children on demand. This constructor is appropriate for
> list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the
> builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

```dart
 class TournamentHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const TournamentHome({Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      width: 400,
                      height: 200,
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Card(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: tournaments.length),
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"--web-renderer", "html"
```

For me, I **removed** the above build/run flag, and the errors are gone. I added it in my launch.json awhile ago and totally forgot it was there.